# Can I use SKScene for material on an Obj file loaded in SceneKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit, apple-model-io

My goal is to be able to tap on a specific model and color the surface. I have managed to do this with generic SCNSphere, SCNBox, etc.

I set it up like this, and it basically works for SCNSphere, etc:

```
let node = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)

let material = SCNMaterial()
        
material.specular.contents = SKColor.init(white: 0.1, alpha: 1)
material.shininess = 2.0;
        
material.normal.contents = "wood-normal.png"
        
let skScene = SKScene.init(size: CGSize(width: SPRITE_SIZE, height: SPRITE_SIZE))
skScene.backgroundColor = SKColor.orange
skScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
material.diffuse.contents = skScene
    
geometry.firstMaterial = material

scnScene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

[image]

However, when I load a `.obj` file and try to set the material with a SKScene I don't get anything. Here is how I set up the `obj`

```
let bundle = Bundle.main
let path = bundle.path(forResource: name, ofType: "obj")
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
let asset = MDLAsset(url: url as URL)
        
guard let object = asset.object(at: 0) as? MDLMesh else {
    print("Failed to get mesh from obj asset")
    return
}

let material = SCNMaterial()
material.specular.contents = SKColor.init(white: 0.1, alpha: 1)

let skScene = SKScene.init(size: CGSize(width: SPRITE_SIZE, height: SPRITE_SIZE))
skScene.backgroundColor = SKColor.orange
skScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
material.diffuse.contents = skScene

let geometry = SCNGeometry.init(mdlMesh: object)
let node = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
node.geometry?.materials = [material]

scnScene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

But as you can see, the color of the teapot is not orange

[image]

My question is, am I doing something wrong in terms of using a SKScene as a material for an `obj` file, or is there some limitation that I'm aware of? I've spent a few hours on this, and am open to suggestions if anyone has any ideas.

Also, in this sort of situation, how do I decide what the size of the SKScene is since I want to arbitrarily wrap the whole mesh with a SKScene?

**Update 1**
I sort of figured something out. My `obj` file doesn't have texture coordinates, only vertices. When I tried another `obj` file with texture coordinates, then the `skScene` seems to have loaded correctly. So I guess my teapot doesn't have uv coordinates, so it can't map the texture. Is there a way to add uv coordinates if the `obj` file doesn't have them already?

Comment: If the object has multiple pieces or nodes you might be setting the material to a piece with no visible geometry. I’d recommend exploring the node hierarchy. And you should use a square scene with a size that is a power of 2 (or at least that’s what works best for textures).

Comment: Hi @EmilioPelaez The object only has one submesh, if that is what you mean. The teapot is the standard one available here https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs148-10-summer/as3/code/as3/teapot.obj

Comment: One thing I noticed is that my teapot.obj is missing `vt` lines, indicating that there is no texture mapping going on... is there a way to add this information?